# Firebase: adding authentication to a react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make sense of [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial#sign-up-with-react-and-firebase).

The handleSubmit method in the sign up form has this method:

```
onSubmit = (event) => {
  const { username, email, passwordOne } = this.state;
  this.props.firebase
    .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
    .then(authUser => {
      this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
      this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({ error });
    });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

It doesn't work. It generates an error that says:

> {code: “auth/argument-error”, message: “createUserWithEmailAndPassword
>   failed: First argument “email” must be a valid string.“}

I have found [this post](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-) which suggests that the tutorial might be behind the current version of firebase (although that doesn't make sense because the post is dated before the tutorial and this tutorial worked when I was trying it with realtime database - where I'm now trying to use it with cloud firestore).  This post suggests that the problem is to do with how the method asks for the values in the form.

I have tried 5 different ways of asking for that information - the console.logs all come back as undefined. I'm out of guesses to find the form values to know how to replace the names given in the onSubmit method.

Currently, the form has the following- the commented alternatives to the current attempt at the onSubmit method are attempts made with references in other tutorials - they don't work either and are just in the post as ideas if anyone else has tried something similar.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import Firebase, { withFirebase } from '../../firebase';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import * as ROUTES from '../../../constants/routes';
import { Button, Modal, Form, Input, Icon, Radio } from 'antd';

const DASHBOARD = '/dash';

const initialValues = {
  name: "",
  password: "",
  email: "",
  role: "",
  createdAt: ''
  }

const CollectionCreateForm = Form.create({ name: 'form_in_modal' })(
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  class extends React.Component {
    render() {

      const { visible, onCancel, onCreate, form } = this.props;
      const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldsError, getFieldError, isFieldTouched } = form;
      const passwordError = isFieldTouched('password') && getFieldError('password');

      return (
        <Modal
          visible={visible}
          title="Register"
          okText="Submit"
          onCancel={onCancel}
          onOk={onCreate}
        >
          <Form layout="vertical">

            <Form.Item label="Name">
              {getFieldDecorator('name', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Your full name' }],
              })(<Input />)}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Password" validateStatus={passwordError ? 'error' : ''} help={passwordError || ''}>
                {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                    rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Create a password' }],
                })(
                    <Input

                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Minimum 6 characters"
                    />,
                )}
            </Form.Item>


            <Form.Item label="Email">
              {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Your email address' }],
              })(<Input />)}
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item label="Select your role">
              {getFieldDecorator('role', {
                initialValue: 'test',
              })(
                <Radio.Group>
                  <Radio value="test1">1</Radio>
                  <Radio value="test2">2 R&D</Radio>

                </Radio.Group>,
              )}
            </Form.Item>

          </Form>
        </Modal>
      );
    }
  },
);

class RegisterBase extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
  };

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  };

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  };

  // handleCreate = values => {
  //   // values.preventDefault();

  //   const { name, email, password } = this.state;

//     Firebase
//     .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
//       return this.auth
//         .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
//         .then((res) => {
//         
// Firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(res.user.uid).set({

//           email: values.email,
//           name: values.name,
//           role: values.role,
//           createdAt: Firebase.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
//         }).then(() => this.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD));
//       })
//       .catch(err => {
//         console.log(err.message);
//       });
//   };
// };
  // handleCreate = () => {
  //   const { form } = this.formRef.props;
  //   form.validateFields((err, values) => {
  //     if (err) {
  //       return;
  //     };
  //   const payload = {
  //   // ...values,
  //   name: values.name,
  //   email: values.email,
  //   organisation: values.organisation,
  //   beta: values.beta,
  //   role: values.role,
  //   // createdAt: Firebase.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  //   }
  //   console.log("formvalues", payload);

  //   Firebase
  //   .auth()
  //   
// .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
  //   console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
  //   Firebase
  //   .collection("users")
  //   .add(payload)
  //   // .then(docRef => {
  //   //     resetForm(initialValues);
  //   // })
  //   .then(e => this.setState({ modalShow: true }))


  //   form.resetFields();
  //   this.setState({ visible: false });
  //   this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);

  // });

    // };
  handleCreate = (event) => {
   // const {  email, password } = this.state;
    const {  email, password } = this.formRef.props.state;



// console.log(this.state.email)

console.log(email);
    this.formRef.props.firebase

    .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(authUser => {
    this.setState({ ...initialValues });
    this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({ error });
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    };

  saveFormRef = formRef => {
    this.formRef = formRef;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal} >
            GET STARTED
          </Button>

            <CollectionCreateForm
              wrappedComponentRef={this.saveFormRef}
              visible={this.state.visible}
              onCancel={this.handleCancel}
              onCreate={this.handleCreate}
            />


      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
}
const Register = compose(
  withRouter,
  withFirebase,
)(RegisterBase);

export default Register;
```

One strange thing is that the console.log(firebase) and console.log(Firebase) both return undefined values. This form is supposed to be using the withFirebase HOC, which is defined as:

```
import React from 'react';
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
export default FirebaseContext;
```

Any ideas on things to try to get the email and password values out of this form?

**NEXT ATTEMPT**
Trying Doppio's suggestion, I am trying:

```
const CollectionCreateForm = Form.create({ name: 'form_in_modal' })(
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  class extends React.Component {
    handleCreate = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
        }
        // Get email, password from form values... 
        // key is the one you use in getFieldDecorator 
        const { email, password } = values;

        this.props.onCreate(values);
      });
    };
```

Note: the console.log in this block doesn't run.

Then, in RegisterBase, I have:

```
handleCreate = (values) => {
      const {  email, password } = values;
      console.log(values)


      this.props.firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then(authUser => {
      this.setState({ ...initialValues });
      this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
        });
        values.preventDefault();
      };
```

This console log does not log the entries in the form. Instead, it logs something with an enormous list that starts with:

> Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode,
>   _dispatchListeners: Array(2), _dispatchInstances: Array(2), nativeEvent: MouseEvent, …}

Then, the error messages say:

> M {code: "auth/argument-error", message:
>   "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be
>   a valid string."}code: "auth/argument-error"message:
>   "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be
>   a valid string."**proto**: Error

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

```
handleCreate = (event) => {
    //   const {  email } = this.props.form.getFieldsValue().email;
      // console.log(this.props.form.getFieldsValue().email)

      // const {  password } = this.props.form.getFieldsValue().password;

      // console.log(withFirebase);
      this.props.firebase
      // .console.log(this.email)
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.props.form.getFieldsValue().email, this.props.form.getFieldsValue().password)
      .then(authUser => {
      this.setState({ ...initialValues });
      this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
        });
        event.preventDefault();
      };
```

This formulation doesn't work either. The error message says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldsValue' of undefined
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

Taking Doppio's new suggestion, I can console log the values input into the form. I tried to adapt the submit handler to use them with the following:

```
handleCreate = () => {
      console.log(this.formRef);
      const { form } = this.formRef.props;
      form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }

        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
        const { email, password } = values;
        console.log(Firebase)
        // console.log(firebase)
        this.props.firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
          .then(authUser => {
            console.log({ authUser });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error });
          });
          form.resetFields();
            this.setState({ visible: false });
            this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);
        // form.resetFields();
        // this.setState({ visible: false });
      });
    };
```

Nothing beyond console.log(Firebase) works. The form just hangs and it does not submit to firebase.

I'm wondering if there is a clue in the first console.log. Its output is enormous - the first part starts:

```
{props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
context: {}
props:
form:
getFieldDecorator: ƒ ()
getFieldError: ƒ (name)
```

I can't find a menu with the form values, or the firebase HOC in it. I haven't searched in every dropdown menu in that log, but I can't find any with suggestive headings that might hold that information.

When I try to do:

```
console.log(this.props.firebase)
```

it does return a big long list of indecipherable things that starts with this line:

```
Firebase {auth: Km, db: Firestore, doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword: ƒ}
```

within that log, under a menu labelled 'a' - the details of my firebase app are logged.  Am I supposed to concatenate references to each of those menu headings after this.props.firebase to get the method to run?

**NEXT INSIGHT**

```
handleCreate = () => {
      console.log(this.formRef);
      const { form } = this.formRef.props;
      form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }


    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
    const { email, password } = values;
    // console.log(Firebase)
    // console.log(this.form.props.firebase)
    // console.log(this.formRef.props)
    console.log(this.props.firebase)
    this.props.firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
      .console.log("try to check if create worked", values.email)
      .then(authUser => {
        console.log("logging user", { authUser });
        this.setState({ ...initialValues });
        this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });
      form.resetFields();
        this.setState({ visible: false });
        this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);
    // form.resetFields();
    // this.setState({ visible: false });
  });
  // form.preventDefault();
};
```

The last console.log in this method that works is the one that says: console.log(this.props.firebase). The rest don't get recognised in the console. If this.props.firebase is recognised, is it possible that it's the wrong thing to get - maybe I'm supposed to be looking inside the long list of drop down menus it returns for something that looks like the auth const in my firebase config. Does that sound like a logical line of enquiry?

**NEXT CLUE**

In this attempt, I'm trying to log the value of firebase.auth instead of firebase.auth(). My firebase config defines this.auth as firebase.auth(). The logged value returns another pile of gibberish that I can't interpret, but which starts with:

```
Km {l: false, settings: Al, app: FirebaseAppImpl, b: ni, O: Array(0), …}
B: null
```

One of the drop down menus within this log is labelled "a" and has a sub menu labelled "B" which has my firebase app project in it. I'm wondering if I'm supposed to find something that can traverse all of these drop down menus to get the authentication tool to work?

Ultimately - trying this doesn't make much difference - the form still hangs and does nothing once the firebase method starts... but it logs a different value and I'm wondering if figuring out what is going on in all of these drop down menus is a path to salvation? If so, where is the key to finding out what all of the letters and acronyms mean?

```
handleCreate = () => {
      console.log(this.formRef);
      const { form } = this.formRef.props;
      form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }

        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
        const { email, password } = values;
        // console.log(Firebase)
        // console.log(this.form.props.firebase)
        // console.log(this.formRef.props)
        console.log("check before firebase", this.props.firebase.auth)
        this.props.firebase
          // .auth
          .auth()
          .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
          .console.log("try to check if create worked", values.email)
          .then(authUser => {
            console.log("logging user", { authUser });
            this.setState({ ...initialValues });
            this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error });
          });
          form.resetFields();
            this.setState({ visible: false });
            this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);
        // form.resetFields();
        // this.setState({ visible: false });
      });
      // form.preventDefault();
    };
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

This attempt tries to use .set instead of .add

It still returns an error that says:

> M {code: "auth/argument-error", message:
>   "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be
>   a valid string."}

```
handleCreate = event => {
                const { name, email, password } = this.state;
          console.log(this.props.firebase)
                this.props.firebase
                  .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                  .then(authUser => {

                    return this.props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set(
                      {
                        name,
                        email,

                      },
                      { merge: true },
                    );
                  })
                //   .then(() => {
                //     return this.props.firebase.doSendEmailVerification();
                //   })
                  .then(() => {
                    this.setState({ ...initialValues });
                    this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
                  })
                  .catch(error => {

                  });
                event.preventDefault();
              };
```

The output of the console log has the whole Firebase class set out in my config - which starts with:

> Firebase {doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword: ƒ,
>   doSignInWithEmailAndPassword: ƒ, doSignOut: ƒ, doPasswordReset: ƒ,
>   doPasswordUpdate: ƒ, …} auth: Km {l: false, settings: Al, app:
>   FirebaseAppImpl, b: ni, O: Array(0), …}

I have tried amending this to insert .auth and .auth() after this.props.firebase, but it returns an error saying those are not functions.

**AN UNHELPFUL ASIDE BEFORE THE NEXT ATTEMPT:**

I'm trying to figure out what the values in the form are called and have now lost access to the console log. It gives a message that says:

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

I'll start investigating what's gone wrong to make this happen next.

Meanwhile, here is the next attempt:

```
handleCreate = event => {
    const { name, email, password } =  this.formRef.props.state;
    console.log(email)
    console.log(name)
    this.props.firebase
        .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(authUser => {

        return this.props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set(
            {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,

            },
            { merge: true },
        );
        })
        .then(() => {
        this.setState({ ...initialValues });
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });

    event.preventDefault();
    };          

  saveFormRef = formRef => {
    this.formRef = formRef;
  };
```

It seems to get past the previous problem. The new error message says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I don't know if this is a step forward or backwards. But am pausing this line of enquiry while I figure out why I can't use the console log anymore.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I am trying to figure out what the form values are called to figure out how to give them to firebase.

The console.logs are ignored with each of these variations, but the error messages vary with each attempt. This attempt generates an error message that says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

```
handleCreate = event => {
    const  name =  this.formRef.props.getFieldValue.name;
    const  email =  this.formRef.props.email;
    const  password =  this.formRef.props.password;
    console.log(this.formRef.props.getFieldValue.email);
    console.log(this.form.props.getFieldValue.email);
    console.log(this.formRef.props.getFieldValue.name);
    this.props.firebase
        .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(authUser => {

        return this.props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set(
            {
            name: this.formRef.props.getFieldValue.name,
            email: email,

            },
            { merge: true },
        );
        })
        .then(() => {
        this.setState({ ...initialValues });
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });

    event.preventDefault();
    };
```

Comment: Apparently `this.state.email` is not a valid string value. You might want to `console.log(email)` right before the call to `doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword` to see what value is *does* contain.

Comment: that's the thing - all the console.log entries come back as undefined. I have put a console.log(email) at every line starting under the const where it gets defined. The first one returns an error that says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined and the rest get ignored. I can't find how to find where it is defined.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with firebase, You are using ant design form, and from the look of it, some of it is not as in documentation. https://ant.design/components/form/

Comment: @Doppio - yes - AntDesign, adapted to use the tutorial. It worked fine when the database was realtime database - and without authentication. It posted a form that created a user in a user table. Now, the adaptation is to add firebase auth and move to cloud firestore - and I can't find how to find the value of email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally.

The handle submit works like this:

```
handleCreate = () => {
    const { form } = this.formRef.props;
    form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) {
        return;
      };
    const payload = {
    // ...values,
    name: values.name,
    email: values.email,
     // createdAt: Firebase.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }
    console.log("formvalues", payload);

    this.props.firebase
    .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
    .then(authUser => {
    return this.props.firebase.user(authUser.user.uid).set(
        {
        name: values.name,
        email: values.email,
        },
        { merge: true },
    );
    })
    // .then(docRef => {
    //     resetForm(initialValues);
    // })
    .then(e => this.setState({ modalShow: true }))


    form.resetFields();
    this.setState({ visible: false });
    this.props.history.push(DASHBOARD);

  });

    };

  saveFormRef = formRef => {
    this.formRef = formRef;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal} >
            GET STARTED
          </Button>

            <CollectionCreateForm
              wrappedComponentRef={this.saveFormRef}
              visible={this.state.visible}
              onCancel={this.handleCancel}
              onCreate={this.handleCreate}
            />


      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
}
```

The firebase config is like this:

```
user = uid => this.db.doc(`users/${uid}`);
```

There is still an issue in the submit handler - which creates this notice, but I have seen this before and will update this answer when I find how to stop watching changes in the form.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the
>   componentWillUnmount method.

Answer (score -1):

Usually I would suggest using `onSubmit` props on `Form`

But in your case, to avoid changing too much.
You can access form's current value by

`this.props.form.getFieldsValue()` or `this.props.form.validateFields();` if you want to validate first.

```
// Change your handleCreate in RegisterBase  to accept values as first parameter
handleCreate = (values) => {
  // const {  email, password } = values;
  const {  email, password } = values;
}

const CollectionCreateForm = Form.create({ name: 'form_in_modal' })(
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  class extends React.Component {

    handleCreate = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          // Get email, password from form values... 
          // key is the one you use in getFieldDecorator 
          const { email, password } = values;
          this.props.onCreate(values); 
        }

      });
    }

    render() {

      const { visible, onCancel, form } = this.props;
      const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldsError, getFieldError, isFieldTouched } = form;
      const passwordError = isFieldTouched('password') && getFieldError('password');

      return (
        <Modal
          visible={visible}
          title="Register"
          okText="Submit"
          onCancel={onCancel}
          onOk={this.handleCreate}
        >
          <Form layout="vertical">

            <Form.Item label="Name">
              {getFieldDecorator('name', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Your full name' }],
              })(<Input />)}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Password" validateStatus={passwordError ? 'error' : ''} help={passwordError || ''}>
              {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Create a password' }],
              })(
                <Input
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Minimum 6 characters"
                />,
              )}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Email">
              {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Your email address' }],
              })(<Input />)}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Select your role">
              {getFieldDecorator('role', {
                initialValue: 'test',
              })(
                <Radio.Group>
                  <Radio value="test1">1</Radio>
                  <Radio value="test2">2 R&D</Radio>
                </Radio.Group>,
              )}
            </Form.Item>

          </Form>
        </Modal>
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried moving the handleSubmit to the form - it doesn't generate any error messages, but it also doesn't do anything - the form freezes and the modal just locks in place - no submission.

Comment: Is your other suggestion that I leave the submit handler where I have it and use it like so to get to the email value:   const {  email } = this.props.form.getFieldsValue().email? I tried this, but it generates an error that says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldsValue' of undefined

Comment: Oh, I didn't see where you put your "submit" button. Now I saw it, you bind form submission to modal isOk props. So the reason it froze because form isn't submitted. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Which one of the handleCreate methods do I put the firebase methods in?

Comment: Now I have 2 handle create methods and neither of them has the firebase bit in it

Comment: the one that is wrapped with withFirebase "RegisterBase"

Comment: I also tried logging the output of    console.log(this.props.form.getFieldsValue().email) in Register Base. It gives an error that says:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldsValue' of undefined

Comment: Yes, that is correct your RegisterBase don't have "this.props.form", only Components that is wrapped with Form.create() will have that. So what we are doing is pass those values from this.props.form to RegisterBase via onCreate props. (this.props.onCreate(values); ), try console.log "values" that got passed through. on the first line of handleCreate (in RegisterBase) add "console.log(values);

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion properly - I updated the post to add the changes that I tried above, together with the error messages.

Comment: These console.logs don't work. Perhaps I misunderstood your suggestion, but it isn't working to get the form values

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I can't get this to work. I can't actually get any of the values to log in the console - I have tried logging each line - but none of them render. I may have misunderstood your suggestions - but thanks anyway for trying to help me figure this out

Comment: Ok, my mistake... I just went and read doc how to use form in modal, and I think it's as what you used before.

Comment: Ok, my mistake... I just went and read doc how to use form in modal, and I think it's as what you used before.

Comment: @Mel I think the tutorial you follow is over complicated. I created a simple version that use Ant Modal + Form + Firebase
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-darwin-xyff5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark 
(I tested, and it works) please add your own firebase credentials in firebase.js.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help. I tried your code sandbox and cannot get it to work. The modal does not hide after the submit. I can console log the form input values but I cannot get the firebase method to work. Nothing happens- no errors, but no successful submission. I can't log the value of firebase (defined in the withFirebaseHOC) but I can get it to find Firebase - the config file.  I'll post an answer here if I figure it out. Thanks again for trying.